# ConcurrentModificationException even though changing values outside of foreach

Tags: java, exception, concurrentmodification

I have the following code

```
                boolean postojaoJePrijelaz = true;
                epsilonStanja = sljedecaStanja;
                while(postojaoJePrijelaz) {
                    for (String epsilonStanje : epsilonStanja) {
                        for (Prijelaz trenutniPrijelaz : prijelazi) {
                            postojaoJePrijelaz = false;
                            if (trenutniPrijelaz.postojiPrijelaz(epsilonStanje.trim(), "$")) {
                                sljedecaStanja.addAll(trenutniPrijelaz.getSkupIzlaznihStanja());
                                epsilonSljedecaStanja.addAll(trenutniPrijelaz.getSkupIzlaznihStanja());
                                postojaoJePrijelaz = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    epsilonStanja = epsilonSljedecaStanja;
                    epsilonSljedecaStanja.clear();
                }
```

And the compiler gives e `ConcurrentModificationException` even though i set `epsilonStanje=epsilonSljedecaStanja` after I already finished my foreach loop. I tried debuggng, but can't seem to fix this.
The program that I'm making is single-threaded

EDIT:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:859)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:831)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:55)
```

Comment: Can you post the Stackstrace you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`epsilonStanja` and `epsilonStanja` both are pointing to the same object as shown below.

```
            epsilonStanja = sljedecaStanja;

            for (String epsilonStanje : epsilonStanja) {
                ...
                sljedecaStanja.addAll(trenutniPrijelaz.getSkupIzlaznihStanja());
                ...
            }
```

you can't add data while iterating.

Solution: create a separate list and finally merge it as per your requirement or try below code:

```
epsilonStanja.addAll(sljedecaStanja);
```

Comment: Could I solve it with just epsilonStanja.addAll(sljedecaStanja)? Is that a good practice?

Comment: No you can't add anything while iterating the same list.

Comment: I meant before I go into the list. So i wouldn't do epsilonStanja = sljedecaStanja, but I would do epsilonStanja.add(sljedecaStanja). Then they wouldn't be pointing at the same place right?

Comment: absolutly right. use `addAll()` instead of `add()` to add a list in another list.

Comment: use `epsilonStanja.addAll(sljedecaStanja);`

Comment: Yes,yes I meant `addAll()`, it was a typo

Answer (score 1):

you are assigning the reference of list sljedecaStanja to epsilonStanja. This is the issue.. Try

```
epsilonStanja = new ArrayList<String>(sljedecaStanja);
```